# OpenLayers3 no refresh WMS in zoom-in

Tags: reactjs, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have an aplication, made with OpenLayers3, GeoServer and ReactJS, showing some WMS. And for a strange reason I can't manage to refresh the image when I zoom in ONLY if the screen resolution is wider that 1314px. It's very strange, if the resolution is for example 1310, I can do normally zoom-in and zoom-out and the wms got refreshed after every zoom, BUT, if the resolution is wider than 1315px, ONLY zoom out works, but not zoom in.

Any one had experimented something like this before?

This is how I'm calling the wms (ReactJS):

```
    var map = this.state.map;
    var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://spif.XX.XX:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'cite:biodent_clientes'},
            serverType: 'geoserver'
        })
    });
    this.state.layersMaServer = wmsLayer;
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

There's no problem with GeoServer, the WMS are well loaded after every zoom-in or out, but I don't know why at zooming in isn't been refreshed on client side (broser). If I zoom-out just a little bit, then the image is refreshed with the correct wms, but why only under 1314px!

Any help, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your WMS server hasn't a size limitation?

Comment: GeoServer sends the correct image, I can see them all in the "Network" of Chrome Dev, but ONLY when the size of the screen isn't wider than 1315px the app it refresh it. But the images files are well generated. Plus, there's no error messages at geoserver logs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Tiled WMS instead:

```
var map = this.state.map;
var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://spif.XX.XX:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'cite:biodent_clientes'},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
});
this.state.layersMaServer = wmsLayer;
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

Comment: I've tried many times using tiles without success. I made this thread too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662136/openlayers-geoserver-tilewms-are-displaying-wrong?noredirect=1#comment76393502_44662136  (I've just test with your code, it's the same behavior)