# OpenLayers, Geoserver: TileWMS are displaying wrong

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I'm trying to display some WMS with tiles, but at every zoom (in or out) the images are displaying wrong, with wrong proportions. This is how I'm creating the tile:

```
    var map = this.state.map;
    var layers =
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://XX.XX.XX:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
                params: {'LAYERS': 'cite:clientes_ex', 'TILED': true, 'VERSION': '1.3.0',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png8', 'WIDTH': 256, 'HEIGHT': 256, 'CRS': 'EPSG:3857'},
                serverType: 'geoserver'
            })
        })
    map.addLayer(layers);
```

This is what happens.
[image]

This is another example, in zooms very far way from the map:
[image]

Any idea how could I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you try without tiles?

Comment: It happens this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641353/openlayers3-no-refresh-wms-in-zoom-in/44646799#44646799

Comment: is this a dynamic heat map? - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244789/geoserver-heatmap-wms-style-problem

Comment: Yes it is. I'll check that thread, thanks. Edit: well, the solution is not to use Tiles in heatmaps, and that brings me to the next thread that I already made in my previous comment..